# Delete symmetric values from database

Tags: mysql

I have database with values

```
A | B
1 | 2
2 | 1
2 | 2
3 | 3
4 | 1
1 | 4
```

How to ignore reversed values 4,1 and 2,1 and return only?

```
A | B
1 | 2
2 | 2
3 | 3
1 | 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select t.* from tablename t
where not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where A = t.B and B = t.A and B > A
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6UkKGYdiiCzDMhUUYvuV2N/1).
Results:

```
| A   | B   |
| --- | --- |
| 1   | 2   |
| 2   | 2   |
| 3   | 3   |
| 1   | 4   |
```